# How to connect work computer to Ethernet at hotels

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I travel for work and my work equipment only connects via Ethernet. I have stayed at so many shady airbnbs just for Ethernet. I know of mobile hotspots but not sure if it would be fast enough. Is there any type of mobile router/modem I can buy so that I can stay at places like hotels that only offer WiFi? Or is there a device that can connect to via WiFi and output Ethernet? Sorry don’t know the correct terms. Any advice is immensely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just carry a USB Wireless Adapter?  Very Simple to do.

Comment: I’ve never heard of that. I’m not good with computers. Do you have any recommendations? Like brand, etc?

Comment: Look on Amazon for a good quality USB Wireless Adapter.  Very common.

Comment: Wonderful will do thank you so much!!!

Comment: @John it is very likely the reason the computer cannot connect WiFi is not a hardware limitation but policies applied by her employer. A USB-WiFi dongle will not fix this, and will be cause for problems with her employer.

Comment: @Autumn you should be speaking to your employer regarding this need. If they expect you to work from hotels, they will need to provide you with equipment necessary to do this that meets their requirements. They will also need to set up the policies and software to support this as well. You should NOT go out and purchase hardware to connect to your work computer until after you have spoken with your employer's IT staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A device that can connect to WiFi and output Ethernet, or serve a similar purpose is your phone. Most Android phones have the capability to enable USB tethering from settings (advanced network settings, together with proxy configuration, bluetooth PAN and WiFi hotspot, but WiFi hotspot disables WiFi so can only forward 4G network.). The USB tethering allows your computer to use the WiFi from your phone. iPhones do not have this functionality. Android USB tethering works on both Windows and MacOS, I don't know if it works on all systems with custom OS. It should also work on Linux but I haven't tested that. If you have a long charger this can actually be very handy as it allows you to place your phone, which has a pretty good WiFi antenna, a bit further away or on top of something so it has more reach.

There are also mobile routers that use 4G network to host a WiFi network you can connect to. I had one from TP-Link that did this. If you have a phone, it can do the exact same thing via tethering or hotspot. It's also possible to find devices that plug into a wall outlet, connect to WiFi and output Ethernet. I don't know if that's faster than just directly connecting to WiFi.

Comment: I do have an iPhone unfortunately but do you have any recommendations on the other options? When I google it I don’t understand what exactly I’m looking for lol

Comment: @Autumn It depends on if you want to access the network via 4G network, or via WiFi. If you want to get something that works with a 4G network you have to pay monthly. A WiFi adapter should be a one time purchase.

Comment: If I want to access 4G, what product would you recommend? I’m fine paying monthly as long as the speeds are the best.

Comment: @Autumn The product IS your iPhone (and unlike what this answer mentions I found no authoritative source saying iPhones can't do the same Android does). Addendums: 1. USB tethering works with ANY desktop OS (Windows, MacOS or Linux); for the computer it's an "Ethernet-over-USB" connection like any other and ALL of them have native drivers so it's "plug'n'play. 2. Even if true that iOS can't share WiFi via USB tethering it surely can share your mobile data - https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/iphone/iph45447ca6/ios -. Now, considering this is for work and about a work computer (...)

Comment: (...) please, if you have further questions, address them to your IT department, not random people on the internet. There can be policies in place restricting the internet access that you may have violated already.